# Realm in React Native - TypeError while not using JS Debugging

Tags: realm, react-native

I am Currently developing an app in `react-native` in which I would like to create a Database on the device as well. I found a good library `Realm` to use as a Database storage in my app but I am having error in running it.

- App works fine when I activate `Debug JS remotely`
- Fails and gives error

  > TypeError: Undefined is not a function (evaluating _iterator3[typeof Symbol === "function"...

  when I run it without using `Debug JS remotely`

I need help in determining the cause of my error
What am I missing here?

My code to handle Realm

```js
let userSchema = {
    name : 'User',
    primaryKey : 'id',
    properties : {
        id          :       {type:'string',indexed:true},
        name        :       'string',
        email       :       'string',
        password    :       'string',
   }
}

let realm = new Realm({schema:[userSchema],deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded:true});

export function getAllUsers(){
    try {
        let usersObject = realm.objects('User');
        let userArray = [];

        for(let user of usersObject){
            userArray.push(user);
        }
        return userArray;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error on creation",e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `schema[userSchema]` might be needed to be `schema: [userSchema]`

Comment: sorry that was my typo mistake while writing on StackOverflow.

Comment: I see no error in my code . Still It is not working without using `Debbug JS remotely`

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/1305#issuecomment-333019355